# "There you go" or "There you are"

Tags: word-usage

Suppose a friend advises you too much and you don't like it; you are tired and say to the third person who is a common friend for both of you. You begin to complain and say:

> - There you go, on his high horse again

I need to know if in the sentence above we can use 'are' instead of 'go' or not?

Comment: "There you are" means something completely different from "there you go". Have you consulted any sources on what they mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[there you go](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-you-go) can be used in three ways:

1) when giving something to someone, usually after a request for the thing, such as giving someone goods that they have bought

2) to mean "I told you so"

3) to express the fact that you cannot change a situation so you must accept it.

In British English, **there you are** can only be used for the first meaning, and possibly the second meaning.
In the sentence that you quoted, the intended meaning is the third one, and so you cannot replace it with **there you are**.